# Angular functions defined using Wigner D-functions

Tags: special-functions

How do I properly implement angular functions using Wigner D-functions in Mathematica? Angular functions are commonly used in light scattering calculations and can be defined using Wigner D-functions. The definitions in terms of Legendre polynomials $P^m_n$ are
$$
\tau_{mn1} (\cos \vartheta ) = \frac{d}{d \vartheta} P^m_n (\cos \vartheta ), \quad  \tau_{mn2} (\cos \vartheta ) = \frac{m}{\sin \vartheta} P^m_n (\cos \vartheta ),
$$
but they can also be expressed using the Wigner D-functions $\mathcal{D}^s_{mn}$ with
$$
\tau_{mnp} = - \frac{1}{2} [ n(n+1) \mathcal{D}_{1n}^m + (-1)^p \mathcal{D}_{-1n}^m].
$$
However, I cannot get the results from this last equation to match the results from the Legendre polynomial definition using the built in functions in Mathematica.

The way I've defined the $\tau$ function in Mathematica is:

```
\[Tau][n_, m_, 
  p_, \[Theta]_] := -(1/
   2)*(n*(n + 1)*WignerD[{n, 1, m}, \[Theta]] + (-1)^p*
     WignerD[{n, -1, m}, \[Theta]])
```

Note that the above definitions are from pages 230 and 233 of the book "Light Scattering by Nonspherical Particles" by M. Mishchenko et al. 2000.

Comment: Please add the exact code you've tried

Comment: Have you seen [this sign convention issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189827/26598) in Mathematica?

Comment: Added the Mathematica code for $\tau$ that I've used.

Comment: Are you sure the factor $n(n+1)$ only multiplies one of the Wigner D functions and not the other? The formula looks wrong, maybe there's a typo in the book.

Comment: That's the way it's defined in referenced the textbook but you're right that it seems odd. I will look for another source.